# How to hit breakpoint in Visual Studio C# .net WebService while I am sending JSON data from the page through Javascript AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio, web-services

I would like to ask you for help. I have created .net WebService based on the Microsoft WebService Walkthrough tutorial.

This is how my IIS structure looks like. I have a test page running on the localhost and WebService called TemperatureWebService.
[IIS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXkao.png)

Folder structure: visiting localhost (or 127.0.0.1) with a browser, displays page index.html (see the screen with folder structure)
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW2cf.png)

Javascript used in the index.html is following. I am sending dummy JSON data through AJAX to my WebService:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datas = JSON.stringify({ datas: { premenna: "hodnota", jozko: "123" } });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TemperatureWebService/Convert.asmx/TestString",
        dataType: "json",
        data: datas,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log('success' + msg);
        },

    });
});
```

This is the CS service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Convert
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "TemperatureService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Convert : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public Convert () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string premenna;
        public string jozko;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string TestString(RootObject datas)
    {
        string skuska = datas.premenna;
        return skuska;
    }
}
```

And what I would like to do is to hit a breakpoint inside the TestString method. I have tried to do it with Visual Studio:

1. Set the breakpoint into the TestString method
2. Debug -> Attach the process
3. I have selected chrome process where the page was opened (maybe that wasn't the smartest idea but I believed it could work)
4. And refreshed the site in the chrome, but the breakpoint wasn't hit.

I am sure that WebService works, because when I was testing it with simple string it returned what I needed, but debuging was not working for me. I am open to any improvements, maybe I haven't set correctly solution, the code or whatever. I would be very greatful for any improvement. Thank you.

Robert

Comment: try attaching to IIS process instead of chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the project in VS.

1. If TemperatureWebService project is configured to point to http://localhost/TemperatureWebService (right-click > properties > web), and also as a start-project (right-click > set as startup project), then attaching debugger to the associated IIS process works automatically by "running" the project (F5 from within VS).
2. If automatic-debugger-attach won't work (sometimes it gets more complicated than what I described above), then try manually attaching: VS > Debug menu > Attach to Process > locate the process named "w3pw.exe" (might be slightly different on different versions of Windows/IIS, but I'm pretty sure it has "w3" or "www" in the name).

Setting a break-point should then work.

Comment: @h2012 Thank you a lot. 1. solution helped me. I just pressed F5, asmx was opened in the browser, then I went back to the tab with my web page, refreshed it and breakpoint was hit. I am really greatful.